# Hide sheets using the the checkbox and TRUE/FALSE cell value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to make the below formula work with the checkbox function. 
I have set up a new sheet to ensure I get the formula correct, and when I debug it get no errors, and have the trigger set up on "Change" which should therefore work when I check/uncheck the box but sheet 2, does not hide or unhide based on the checkbox. 
This is the MCVE of the code as far as I can tell, and I am trying to extrapolate this into a more complex sheet, once I have this working. When I make the change, therefore using triggering the script, there is no change in the sheet. Sheet 2 is not hidden or unhidden. 
Any help would be most appreciated, I am VERY new to script writing.

Thanks

```
function myFunction() {
  function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2");

  var cell1 = sheet1.getRange('A1');
  if (cell1.getValue() == TRUE) {
    sheet2.hideSheet();
  }

  if (cell1.getValue() == FALSE) {
    sheet2.showSheet();
  }
}
}
```

Made the change to the below and it worked. Thanks for the help

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet 1");
  var sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet 2");

  var cell1 = sheet1.getRange('A1');
  var x= cell1.getValue();
  Logger.log("AAAAAAAAAA",x);

  if(cell1.getValue()== false) {
  Logger.log("box not checked");
    sheet2.hideSheet();
  } else if (cell1.getValue() == true) {
    sheet2.showSheet();
  }
```

Comment: I don't see any logging statements which will be invaluable for your debugging purposes. I recommend you use Stackdriver logging, with the `console` class. Those logs will persist for multiple executions.

Comment: Adding logging will help you determine if your chosen trigger is even activating when you perform the action you perform.

Comment: Thanks both, made the change as in the question and it worked. Thanks for the help